# CSS for the following image design

Tags: html, css

```css
.step2 {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 -87px 0 33px;
    padding: 30px 40px 0 40px;
    height: 212px;
    text-align: center;
     }
    .step2:before {
    border-top: 40px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #4060A5;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="step2">
            Step 1
        </div>
</div>
```

I am developing a website but now I got stucked to achieve css for the Steps portion (Step 1, Step 2, Step 3) given in the image below :
  [This is the link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqmDb.png)

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve CSS ?

Comment: I just added the link for the image.Kindly go through it.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Css:
.step2 {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 -87px 0 33px;
    padding: 30px 40px 0 40px;
    height: 212px;

    text-align: center;
}
.step2:before {
    border-top: 40px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #4060A5;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    top: 0;
}

Comment: HTML :
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="step2">
            Step 1
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: @BlackMamba I have now edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with it and adjust the sizes and fonts according to your needs !

```css
span{
  position: absolute;
  width : 100px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 40%;
}
.orange {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;   
    position:relative;
    background-color:#333;
    height:100px !important;
    width:100px !important;
    z-index:3;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-right:2px;
}

.orange:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
    border-left: solid 15px #333;
}

.green {
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #333;
    height:100px !important;
    width:100px !important;
    z-index:2;
    margin-right:2px;
    float: left;
}

.green:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
    border-left: solid 15px #333;
}
.green:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
    border-left: solid 15px white;
}

.blue {
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #333;
    height:100px !important;
    width:100px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.blue:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.blue:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 50px transparent;
    border-left: solid 15px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="orange"><span>Step 1</span></div>
<div class="green"><span>Step 2</span></div>
<div class="blue"><span>Step 3</span></div>
```